# Add a condition to start a function in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have created a script that open all csv and xlsx files a directory contains. My issue appears when my directory doesn't contain one type of file. (ex : 5 csv and 0 xlsx    OR   0 csv and 14 xlsx)
Here is what my script looks like:

```
#step 1
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.csv')
csv_df <- lapply(file.list, read.csv, header=TRUE)

#step 2
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
xlsx_df <- lapply(file.list, read_excel_function)
```

I got an error message:

```
Error in do.call("rbind", xlsx_df) :
le second argument doit être une liste (the second argument must be a list)
```

Do you have any idea on how to add a condition that skip one step if the list.files return nothing?

Comment: hint: what is the [`length`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/length.html) of `file.list` when it is empty? can you use the `length` as a condition in an `if` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just execute the read/combine command only if `file.list` is non-empty. For example:

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.csv')
if (length(file.list) > 0){
  csv_df <- lapply(file.list, read.csv, header=TRUE)
}
```

You could also add an `else` condition if you want `csv_df` to have some other value in the case that there's no relevant files.